# Is there any way to pass a variable from ReactJS to a CSS stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, keyframe

I'm writing a scrolling ticker with a variable number of components, so I need it to change how far `translate3d` moves it based on the number of components. The only way I can think to do this is to somehow pass it a number from the `JSX` file, but I can't find a way to do that. Is there any way to pass the `CSS` a variable, or some other way to do what I'm wanting?

Comment: You could use the javascript to manually add an inline style of the translate3d with the proper variables you want. This may help: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: CSS doesn't *have* variables.  You have to work with properties of the elements in the document tree.

Comment: @Press I've been trying to do that, but the keyframes thing doesn't seem to work in the inline styling.

Comment: Trying to follow the example there for at least referencing the animation, it complains about the `-` at the front of `-webkit-animation:`

Comment: @SaintWacko you can't do keyframes/create/edit animations inline. You would need to come up with a way to do all that via inline styles (at least afaik) or apply a class that references your variable. So `class="translate3d var30"` could be something like `transform: translate3d(-30px, 0, 0);` or whatever you're doing. It's not a good solution but without knowing 100% what you're trying to do can only guess.

Comment: @SaintWacko also, based on their example from the link, you do `WebkitTransition` or `WebkitAnimation` instead of the standard `-wekbit-` prefeix.

Comment: @Press I currently have a keyframes block which is ending the transform at `translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)`. I need to replace that `-100%` with `number of elements x width of element`. The range is wide enough that it is unfortunately not feasible to have a separate class for each possibility. PS: Changing it to WebkitAnimation did work for that bit, thank you!

Comment: @SaintWacko is this (http://codepen.io/wildbeard/pen/mOQggN) what you're looking to do?

Comment: @Press Yes, something like that, although that example doesn't seem to be animating. The way it's dynamically assigning the style is exactly what I'm trying to do, though.

Comment: It looks like it's not possible to do exactly what I'm wanting to do. I think I can work around it with the `WebkitTransition`, if I could just get it so `translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)` was actually moving it 100% of the width to the left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130738/discussion-between-press-and-saintwacko).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several [« **CSS in JS** »](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js) libraries which allows you to add `keyframes` to your components animations. As you write your styles in your JavaScript, you can directly use your components props/states or some other constants to create your components styles.

The 3 following libraries have a keyframes support (I've personally been using the first one):

## Styled-Components ([GitHub](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components))

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const rotate360 = keyframes`
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
`;

const Rotate = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  animation: ${rotate360} 2s linear infinite;
`;
```

## Glamor ([GitHub](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor))

```
import { css } from 'glamor'

let bounce = css.keyframes('bounce', {
  '0%': { transform: 'scale(0.1)', opacity: 0 },
  '60%': { transform: 'scale(1.2)', opacity: 1 },
  '100%': { transform: 'scale(1)' }
})

<div {...css({
  animation: `${bounce} 2s`,
  width: 50, height: 50,
  backgroundColor: 'red'
})}>
  bounce!
</div>
```

## Aphrodite ([GitHub](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite))

```
const translateKeyframes = {
  '0%': { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
  '50%': { transform: 'translateX(100px)' },
  '100%': { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
};

const opacityKeyframes = {
  'from': { opacity: 0 },
  'to': { opacity: 1 }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  zippyHeader: {
    animationName: [translateKeyframes, opacityKeyframes],
    animationDuration: '3s, 1200ms',
    animationIterationCount: 'infinite',
  },
});

<div className={css(styles.zippyHeader)}>...</div>
```

## More reading about the « CSS in JS » pattern

- [React: CSS in JS (presentation by Christopher Chedeau, Facebook)](https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js) (November 8, 2014)
- [Writing your styles in JS ≠ writing inline styles](http://mxstbr.blog/2016/11/inline-styles-vs-css-in-js/) (November 25, 2016)

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what I was hoping for originally, I did find a way to get this working. It turns out that the reason the `translate3d(100%, 0, 0)` wasn't working was because of flexbox. Once that was removed from the element, I was able to control the speed of the animation by setting the element width and the animation time by dynamically creating those styles in React.