# How can I create multiple instances of a React component (having an infinite animation) with different values for the :root variables

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, css-animations

I am very new to using Javascript + CSS + React, and badly stuck. Appreciate any help!! Described below is a stripped down version, to highlight the key request

**Description of my react component:**

A dot that vertically moves from point A to point B infinitely on screen. Point A and Point B are randomly assigned dots on my screen plane. The two points have same x coordinates but different y coordinates to enable the vertical motion. So each journey from A to B has three random parameters: x, y1, and y2. Once it reaches B it restarts at A.

**Desired state:**

Ask 1 - Once the dot reaches finishing point B, I hope to be able to re-randomise x, y1, and y2 for my component.

Ask 2 - I need to have several instances of this component (say 20), each of which has their own random thing going on independently.

**My approach so far:**

Step 1: In the component's css file, I write the animation code with `--x`, `--y1`, and `--y2` as variables in the `:root` class:

```
:root {                 /* Values assigned are just fallback values */
  --x: 100px;
  --y1: 10px;
  --y2: 400px;
}

.spark div {            /* spark is the `className` for the div that contains the dot (shown in Step 2) */
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--x);
  top: var(--y2);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  animation: myOrbit 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes myOrbit {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(var(--y1));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(var(--y2));
  }
}
```

Step 2: I use `document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--x", x + "vw");` in the component's jsx code like below:

```
const Spark = () => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--x", Math.random()*500 + "px");
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--y1", Math.random()*500 + "px");
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--y2", Math.random()*500 + "px");

  return (
    <div className="spark">
      <div />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Spark;
```

Step 3: I call this component in the App.js using the below code:

```
import Spark from "./components/Spark.js";

const App = () => {
  return (
      <div className="sparks">
        <Spark />
        <Spark />
        <Spark />
        <Spark />
        <Spark />
      </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Step 4: I bring everything together using index.js and index.html:

*src/index.js*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App.js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

*public/index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>visor</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%">
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Problem:**

1. The random x, y1, and y2 values generated by the last instance of the Spark component gets applied to all the previous instances. So I only get 5 overlapping dots instead of 5 different ones
2. I am unable to change x, y1, y2 between subsequent A-B loops. I am not sure where to even start  to do that

Thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start of by stating that React (out of the box) doesn't have a straightforward way to add animations that take variables from the react component.
If you're plan on doing anything complexer that this, I urge you to have a look at the libraries that aid with that. [Some options are discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173272/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-variable-from-reactjs-to-a-css-stylesheet)

**The main problem you seem to face is how to apply an animation per dot**.
That doesn't interfere with the logic of the other dots.
In order to do that we'll create a separate animation per Spark and feed a random x, y1 and y2 created in the component.
The second problem you seem to face is how to assign new random values when the animation is done, react provides hooks for that, we can use `onAnimationIteration` to trigger some code to handle that.
[In this codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-lake-e6ool?file=/src/spark.js) you can find the entire piece working together.

```
import React from "react";

const Spark = () => {
  const name = `spark_${Math.random()}`.replace(".", ""); // create a random name
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(Math.random() * 500); // keep state for x
  const [y1, setY1] = React.useState(Math.random() * 500); // y1
  const [y2, setY2] = React.useState(Math.random() * 500); // and y2
  // build the animation string
  const animationStyle = `{ 0% {transform: translate(${x}px,${y1}px);} 100% {transform: translate(${x}px,${y2}px);} }`; 

  React.useEffect(() => { // useEffect runs whenever the provided dependancies change. in the effect well create the stylesheet and add it to the dom
    // Creating a style element, to add the keyframes
    const styleSheet = document.createElement("style");
    styleSheet.type = "text/css";
    styleSheet.id = x;
    document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
    // Adding The Keyframes
    styleSheet.sheet.insertRule(
      `@keyframes ${name} ${animationStyle}`,
      styleSheet.length
    );
    // return a cleanup function for when the element unmounts
    return () => styleSheet.remove(); // this cleanup will remove the stylesheet when it's not needed anymore
  }, [animationStyle, name, x]);

  return (
    <div className="spark">
      <div
        style={{ //you can pass css styles to the dom via react,
          animation: `${name} 1s linear infinite`, // here we set the animation
          transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y1}px)` // here we provide some initial values. 
        }}
        onAnimationIteration={() => { // react can listen to dom event,  here we trigger some code eacht time the animation starts a new iteration
          setX(Math.random() * 500);  // set new values 
          setY1(Math.random() * 500);
          setY2(Math.random() * 500);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Spark;
```

You can render multiples by returning an array of components

```
import "./styles.css";
import Spark from "./spark";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="sparks">
      {Array(20)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, i) => (
          <Spark key={i} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Let me try and implement this!